# Are SSDs reliable today?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I want to buy an ASUS laptop with OLED and I need 2TB of internal storage.
The only laptop that still has a HDD slot is no longer in the ASUS offer.

For me it's quite strange that laptops with HDD are no longer manufactured.
I now have two 1TB HDDs in mine, the second one is on the optical drive. I really need this storage space.

It seems that the only option is to take one of those ASUS laptops, without HDD support, and change the 512 GB SSD that it has by default, with a 2 TB one.

The problem is that I was left with a fear of SSDs. Before, when the technology had just appeared, it was said that SSDs are not reliable, that they die out of nowhere, and that you should only keep the operating system on them and the important data on the HDD.

Is it still the same nowadays? I think that if a big company like ASUS has completely given up on HDDs, it knows something.
Maybe SSDs have become so efficient that there is no longer a problem that they fail so quickly.

What do you think ?

I have an SSD in this laptop of mine, bought in 2020, with which I haven't had any problems until today...

Comment: They have been on par with HDDs for years now and as with any storage medium, you should have backups anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are reliable,even **more reliable than HDDs**. [New Backblaze Data Confirms SSDs Are More Reliable Than Hard Drives](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/backblaze-confirms-ssds-more-reliable-than-hdds)

The only problem is that it is not wise to buy more SSDs from one series. I read somewhere and I can't find the source anymore that if the error doesn't manifest itself within 2 weeks then it is already unlikely to appear and the disk will be destroyed by overwrites.
As for brands, I personally prefer Samsung SSDs.

In my experience and I've seen dozens of samsung drives I've only seen one broken.

Comment: No, they're extremely reliable but definitely not more reliable than HDDs for very long term usage. After decades the magnetic on the tapes and disks are still there, but the electrons on the SSD transistors already escaped out

Comment: @phuclv Sorry, but you're just not right. Who else than backblaze can be more right? Nobody. They have by far the most experience. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/backblaze-confirms-ssds-more-reliable-than-hdds

Comment: did they measure for decades? It's been well known that NAND cells will lose their content after a long enough time. For a short enough cycle, yes, that's why SSDs nowadays have 5-year warranty

Comment: Who cares if the HDD or SSD works for decades? A disk is supposed to work for 5 years as long as it has performance, then new technologies come along and so on. 
These long term things are for a completely different discussion. I don't want to see any hardware older than 5 years on servers and classic computers, then it is obsolete and unusable technologically, morally obsolete and has a technological debt.

Comment: No body cares whether you care or not, but many people care. Maybe the OP cares. People still use retrocomputing for various things and they care whether the game card will run in the next decade

Comment: How much is many people? 1-2% ? i hope we will not be talking about 1-2 percent of people here.

Answer (score 3):

**For what it is worth:**

Information regarding HDD "life expectancy" from Backblaze, a company that uses an excessive amount of drives;
https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-life-expectancy/

And SSD:s, based on a very limited experience in comparison, I'd say they are pretty reliable today - I have yet to see a failed SSD, having owned three or four of them personally, and living in a corporate environment with many more - never heard of a failed SSD (with a general three to five year PC update).

So personally I'm not expecting SSD:s to be (divergently(wd?)) less reliable than HDD:s.
The problem in my opinion is the price range, say 4 times higher in price (Sweden), and with space/size availability being lower.

*edit: Using Samsung SSD's exclusively*

Answer (score 3):

> Are SSDs reliable today?

There are brands that produce reliable SSD's that run as good or better than traditional HDD's. There are also brands that are not as reliable that may die suddenly.

In any case, budget SSD's are often less reliable. If an SSD is priced very competitively, it may not be the best one. You will want to look for tests and reviews to find out which brands are in your reach that you can consider.

I have good experience with: Samsung, Kingston and Adata

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on somehow a wrong assumption, that is *"SSDs used to be less reliable than HDDs"*. In fact you wrote *"**it was said that** SSDs are not reliable"*: but "it" was wrong. At very least it was not a universal truth.

A universal truth is that the first available SSDs were very expensive. But not "less reliable" than HDDs.

The second problem is that when talking about "reliability", you should define what you have in mind. HDDs and SSDs have quite different characteristics, and therefore quite different behaviors regarding aging.

**Aging:**

SSDs wear out mostly with the cumulated amount of written data along their life. There are other factors, but this one is by far the main driver.

For HDDs it is more balanced between various factors: number of spin-up/spin-down cycles, number of load/unload cycles, random accesses (thus many displacements of the magnetic heads) rather than sequential accesses, number of hours in operation...

It's important here to make a difference between SSDs and other form of flash memory drives, such as USB keys or memory cards. While they all use flash memory chips, the grade of the chips is not the same, and the controllers of the USB keys/memory cards are usually much less sophisticated than the ones of the SSDs. The role of the controller is critical to reduce the wear out (to make it short, the aim is to balance to the number of writes over the whole memory space, thanks to various internal algorithms). In the past, it's true some low cost SSDs (well, not that much low, but low in comparison to other SSDs at the time) may have had poor controllers, resulting in SSDs rapidly aging (some even had bugged controllers, resulting in data losses)... But when you are going to low cost, you should always expect bad surprises...

Also, what is true is that the end-of-life period of a SSD is usually shorter than the end-of-life period of a HDD. By "end-of-life" period I mean the time interval between the first signs of potential failure (typically when reallocated sectors start appearing) and the failure itself.

**Reliability**

Here we talk about unexpected failures. Like with any electronic device, the electronic parts of a SSD or HDD can fail for "no reason", with no or minimal warning signs. Yes there are more electronic components in a SSD, since the storage itself is made of electronic chips, so more "no reason" to fail... But a HDD has mechanical parts that can fail too. This is particularly true for a HDD in a laptop, that can experience sudden movements or shocks.

Comment: Regarding those alghoritms... If the disk is 90% full, that means the remaining mem cels will be writen more often and they will die soon ?

Comment: @MarusGradinaru No: the controller can identify the "static data" (that correspond to files that have not been updated for a long time) and at some point it moves them from blocks that have a low write count to blocks that have a high write count. The blocks with a low write count are hence assigned to the free space and will be written more often. This is part of the wear-leveling algorithms.

Comment: Wow, that's great ! And all new SSD manufacturers have this alghoritm ? Does Kingston have it too ? I plan to buy one of these...

Comment: @MarusGradinaru it's very difficult to get technical details from the vendors, as they don't want to spoil their technologies to the competitors. We just have to assume that the reputated brands implement the state-of-the-art technologies. Still, you can read this: https://media.kingston.com/pdfs/MKF_283.1_Flash_Memory_Guide_US.pdf